# Variables in VBA for Word 2010

Tags: vba, variables, word-2010

I have this code in VBA for Word 2010:

```
Public LastBodyPage
Sub tryit()
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="AppendixStart"
    LastBodyPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
End Sub

Sub vardel()
    MsgBox Variables.item("LastBodyPage").Value
    MsgBox LastBodyPage
End Sub
```

When the vardel procedure is run, the first message box displays "53" and the second time it displays "50".

Why am I getting different values??

Comment: I'm assuming `Variables` means `Document.Variables`, although I am surprised it would run without the `Document` object being mentioned explicitly. Otherwise, `Variables` must be declared somewhere else in your VBA project, also as a "global variable" similar to `LastBodyPage`.  In any case, the two are not the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at two different things:

The first message box displays something called `Variables.item` (your code does not compile, what is `Variables.item`?).

Anyway, the second message box displays something completely different, it displays `LastBodyPage` which you presumably set using `tryit`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Variables.Items` is part of the [document variables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306281/how-to-store-and-retrieve-variables-in-word-documents) that you can set up and assign values to.

`LastBodyPage` in your `tryit` procedure looks at the bookmark `AppendixStart` which I assume you also set up.

So...

- `AppendixStart` is bookmarked on page 50
- The code `ThisDocument.Variables.Add ("LastBodyPage"), 53` is used to add the document variable somewhere in your code.  This persists between opening & closing the document - so may have been added ages ago.
- Your code uses `ThisDocument.Variables....` rather than just `Variables....`

With those condition I got the same result as you.